# Get the filesystem type for a given path

Tags: shell

Okay, so I'm working with a script that uses rsync, however it might be running any nearly any flavour of unix, including Mac OS X.

The problem is that rsync needs an appropriate --iconv setting in case UTF file-names cause problems, which can be the case on file-systems such as HFS+.

What I need to do is when given a path, find out what type of file-system it resides upon, so that I can fill in an appropriate iconv property for known problem cases.

Or alternatively, if anyone knows of a safe --iconv parameter for rsync that will also work for HFS+; the rsync site recommends --icon=UTF-8,UTF8-MAC, however I expect it won't work on other platforms.

Comment: `df -T ` gives you filesystem given a path, on linux, but it's not going to be the same across all flavors of *nix. You're unlikely to find a single command to do this across everything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your script guess, make it the user's responsibility to set the `RSYNC_ICONV` environment variable as appropriate before running.